# How to convert int number to 0.f in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-progressbar

In my application I want use **animation** for `progressBar` and I write [@Ben P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8298909/ben-p) code.

In below codes get start and end numbers with float numbers such as **0.79f** .

But I want set numbers such as **79** .

**My codes:**

```
    private void setUpObserver() {
        progressBar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                startAnimation(0.65f, 0.0f);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    progressBar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    progressBar.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startAnimation(float startPercent, float endPercent) {
        int width = progressBar.getWidth();
        progressBar.setMax(width);

        int start = (int) (startPercent * width);
        int end = (int) (endPercent * width);
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

        animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animator.setStartDelay(0);
        animator.setDuration(10_000);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int value = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                progressBar.setProgress(value);
            }
        });
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

I change numbers and types from float to int.

but when run application not show me animation and countdown

How can I it?

I want set **`startAnimation(65, 0);`** instance of `startAnimation(0.65f, 0.0f);`

How can I it? please help me

Comment: multiply with 100

Comment: @RanjanDas, can you help me? please send to me code. I am amateur. please my friend

Answer (score 0):

```
private void startAnimation(int startPercent, int endPercent) {
    int width = progressBar.getWidth();
    progressBar.setMax(width);

    int start = (int) (startPercent / 100f * width);
    int end = (int) (endPercent / 100f * width);
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

    animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animator.setStartDelay(0);
    animator.setDuration(10_000);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            int value = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            progressBar.setProgress(value);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here use this method to convert float to int from "0 to 99", remember for 100 you can add extra condition

```
private int convertToInt(float f) {
    String num = f+"";
    String dF = num.substring(num.indexOf('.')+1);
    if(dF.length()==1)
        return (int) (f*10);
    else
        return (int) (f*100);
}
```

}